# How to display marathi font in j2me mobile application?

Tags: java-me

we are making one mobile application in j2me java symbian. we want to display marathi font in our mobile application.we tried searching on various forums but was unable to get a solution related to language support. if not marathi please tried to provide solution trying any language rather than english. how to display marathi font in application and how to use unicode in marathi in j2me.. we need an expert advice on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I have usually seen or implemented similar things done in the past is to create your own font texture and handle all the character drawing yourself. Basically, if the font you want isn't provided for the handset you are targetting, you have to handle all text drawing yourself.

Comment: what if the handset supports the languauge we want..then is there any method to get the desired solution rather than drawing the character myself.

Comment: you may check if that font is supported using a mutable Image. If, after a drawString, the resulting image is not a square or a question mark, then the font is supported.

Comment: If the default font for the handset supports the character you wish to display, you should just be able to use the Graphics.drawString method, as mentioned by Telmo. A particular font (ie: set of characters) cannot be strictly set up by the user; you have to use the default character set for the device. I suggest you look at javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics (particularly the setFont function) and
javax.microedition.lcdui.Font to get a better idea.

Remember that a particular handset might include support for a character set that differs from that of the jvm. drawString is the best way to test